# Haskell Turtle get out of Shell Monad

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

could you please help me with [Turtle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle) library.
I want to write simple program, that calculates disk space usage.
Here is the code:

```
getFileSize :: FilePath -> IO Size
getFileSize f = do
  status <- stat f
  return $ fileSize status

main = sh $ do
  let sizes = fmap getFileSize $ find (suffix ".hs") "."
```

so now I have `sizes` bind of type `Shell (IO Size)`. But I can't just sum it,  with `sum` fold, cause there is `IO Size` in there. If it was something like `[IO Size]` I could pull `IO` monad out of there by using `sequence` to transform it to `IO [Size]`. But I can't do this with `Shell` monad since it is not `Traversable`. So I wrote something like this

```
import qualified Control.Foldl as F

main = sh $ do
  let sizes = fmap getFileSize $ find (suffix ".hs") "."
  lst <- fold sizes F.list
  let cont = sequence lst
  sz <- liftIO $ cont
  liftIO $ putStrLn (show (sum sz))
```

First I folded `Shell (IO Size)` to `[IO Size]` and then to `IO [Size]` to sum list afterwards.
But I wonder if there is more canonical or elegant solution to this, because here I created two lists to accomplish my task. And I throught that `Shell` monad is for manipulating entities in constant space. Maybe there is some `fold` to make `IO (Shell Size)` from `Shell (IO Size)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `IO` action, and you really want a `Shell` action. The usual way to handle that is with the `liftIO` method, which is available because `Shell` is an instance of `MonadIO`.

```
file <- find (suffix ".hs") "."
size <- liftIO $ getFileSize file
```

or even

```
size <- liftIO . getFileSize =<< find (suffix ".hs") "."
```

Fortunately, the `Turtle` package itself offers some size functions you can use directly with `MonadIO` instances like `Shell` [in `Turtle.Prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.10/docs/Turtle-Prelude.html#g:8) so you don't need to use `liftIO` yourself.

Now you actually have to sum these up, but you can do that with `fold` and `sum`.

I would recommend that you avoid breaking open the `Shell` type itself. That should be reserved for adding totally new functionality to the API. That certainly isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I should guess myself for such simple solution. Thats because I trapped myself with `fmap`, where more direct approach should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've managed to get rid of `IO` here by using helper transformation

```
sio :: Shell (IO a) -> Shell a
sio s = Shell (\(FoldShell step begin done) ->
                let step' x a = do
                      a' <- a
                      step x a'
                in
                  _foldShell s (FoldShell step' begin done))
```

But now I wonder is there any simpler solution to this task...